# Create uberjar using sbt-assembly with just the jars from a multiproject build

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a multiproject build and I'm using sbt-assembly to create fat jars.  I'd like to create two jars: one jar that just has the jars created by the project, and then another jar with just the dependencies.   I seem to be able to create the dependency jar fine (assemblyPackageDependency), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a jar with *just* the jars that are produced by the project.   Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Not entirely sure what your setup is; can you use `sbt package`?

Comment: so myproject builds jars a and b.  between them they depend on jars x, y, and z.  I'd like to have one jar that is a and b uberjar'd and another that is x,y,z uberjar'd

Answer (score 0):

- `sbt package` packages only the current sub project.
- `sbt assemblyPackageDependency` includes only the dependencies. Projects marked as `dependsOn` are not included.

`assembly`, `assemblyPackageDependency` or `assemblyPackageScala` are tasks which play with settings defined in `AssemblyOption` to create various packaging configurations. A few relevant options are shown below:

```scala
AssemblyOption(assemblyDirectory: File,
  // include compiled class files from itself or subprojects
  includeBin: Boolean = true,
  includeScala: Boolean = true,
  // include class files from external dependencies
  includeDependency: Boolean = true,
```

A variation of assembly call using config shown below will result in a binary with all sub-projects

```scala
assemblyOption in assemblyPackage := {
    val ao = (assemblyOption in assembly).value
    ao.copy(includeBin = true, includeScala = false, includeDependency = false)
  },
```

---

However if you want to preserve `assembly`, a new task `assemblyPackage` can be created. Snippet from main `build.sbt`

```scala
lazy val assemblyPackage = TaskKey[File]("assemblyPackage", "packages multi-project using sbt-assembly")

lazy val assemblyPackageSettings = Seq(
  // Required packaging configuartion
  assemblyOption in assemblyPackageDependency := {
    val ao = (assemblyOption in assemblyPackageDependency).value
    ao.copy(includeScala = false)
  },
  // Some boiler-plate settings to be copied to new task
  assembledMappings in assemblyPackage       := Assembly.assembledMappingsTask(assemblyPackage).value,
  assemblyPackage                            := Assembly.assemblyTask(assemblyPackage).value,
  test in assemblyPackage := (test in assembly).value,
  assembleArtifact in assemblyPackage := true,
  packageOptions in assemblyPackage      := (packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin)).value,
  assemblyOutputPath in assemblyPackage      := { (target in assembly).value / (assemblyJarName in assemblyPackage).value },
  assemblyJarName in assemblyPackage       := ((assemblyJarName in assemblyPackage)      or (assemblyDefaultJarName in assemblyPackage)).value,
  // Choice of jar name
  assemblyDefaultJarName in assemblyPackage      := { name.value + "-assemblyPackage-" + version.value + ".jar" },
  assemblyOption in assemblyPackage := {
    val ao = (assemblyOption in assembly).value
    ao.copy(includeScala = false, includeDependency = false)
  },
  assemblyPackage := Assembly.assemblyTask(assemblyPackage).value
)

// And use itas
lazy val misc = project.settings(commonSettings ++ assemblyPackageSettings)
  .dependsOn(common)
```

`sbt assemblyPackage` will build `*-assemblyPackage-*jar` files with all dependent sub projects.